# Passing values to spring bean programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have below spring bean.

```
public class Employee2 {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private double salary;


  public Employee2(int id, String name, double salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
  }

 // some logic to call database using above values

}
```

Now i have below config in spring configuration file.

```
<bean id="emp2" class="com.basic.Employee2">
            <constructor-arg name="id" value="" />
            <constructor-arg name="name" value="" />
            <constructor-arg name="salary" value="" />
</bean>
```

Now i cannot hard code the values in above config since they are dynamic.

Now i am getting spring bean programmatically using below code.

```
Employee2 emp = (Employee2)applicationContext.getBean("emp2");
```

Now **how can i pass the values to Employee2 constructor**?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to review the concept of spring context. your bean will be initiated and stored in spring context, which means the constructor is called by spring during context loading.. you cannot call constructor of an class instance because it is already constructed.

Comment: Instance can be constructed later, with lazy loading. Look on  getBean(String name, Object... args) here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html

Comment: pasha, could you please give me any exmple?

Comment: pasha, will it work with only prototype scope?

Answer (score 1):

When you do the bean lookup. Use the varargs getBean method instead to send in arguments to the constructor.

So try something like this:

```
Employee2 emp = (Employee2)applicationContext.getBean("emp2", "someid", "somename", "somesalaray");
```

Comment: trappski, thanks for your answer. Can i keep the constructor configuration in spring file as is without any values? Thanks!

Comment: Have only tried with prototype-scope myself so i don't know.

You can probably keep the configuration as is yes. The getBean() call will override any values in the definition. It _should_ also work even if you define you bean without the arguments:
i.e. like:

    <bean id="emp2" class="com.basic.Employee2" />